# Writing to file in chunks, multiple threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am working on a c# program that reads a large amount of data in chunks, using multiple threads to read the stream concurrently. Each thread has a buffer, it fills it, then I want it to write to the local file, then repeat, continue filling buffer and writing to file until the whole chunk is processed. What’s the best way to write the buffer for each thread after it’s full? If I use a filestream, then I need to create one per thread, otherwise one thread could dispose of the stream after it’s done writing (since the program doesn’t wait for the threads to finish reading, it just starts the reading and returns), but it didn’t seem ideal to have multiple file streams for the same file. If I use one file stream, then each thread needs to seek every time before writing. I used a memory mapped file, created a view accessor of each region of the file that each thread is responsible writing to, then each thread can write to its region without needing to seek. Is this a right usage of memory mapped files or is there a better way?

Comment: *"but it didn’t seem ideal to have multiple file streams for the same file"* -- Why? Does it have performance issues?

Comment: Not sure, I think it does, but not 100% sure. Additionally, that would require constantly seeking which could be expensive, right?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at a solution would be to use a single file stream across multiple threads. In order to synchronise the writing we can lock the stream so that no other thread can write until the current thread has written its data.
However, a problem may occur where other threads are starved if their buffers are filled quickly after writing. (But as you mentioned reading large data, this might not be the case).

I am not sure if you want the data in order of it being read however with this solution, you do not have to worry about seeking the stream as it will seek to the end after each write.

```
public static StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("./file.txt");

public static void writeBuffer(byte[] data)
{
    lock (writer)
    {
        writer.Write(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the threads are writing their buffers to the file, and that could happen in random order, so before the write, we’d need a seek. Is that performant, or is there a better way?

Comment: If you want it in order, you need to ensure via a queue that threads are executed in order. There isn't a way to do it without having to seek back/forward if a thread writes ahead. If you are worried about performance, as long as all threads read at the same rate, it might just be better to write in order using a queue.